# Where can I get a Linux distro iso based on a 2.4 kernel?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, iso-image, kernel

I need to get my hands on an ISO file for a Linux distribution with a 2.4 kernel. I'm looking for an ISO specifically so I can use it with my Oracle VirtualBox.

Since 2.4 is so old these days, I'll explain that I'm looking for it because my company uses an ancient 2.4 uClinux distro on our ancient hardware in our devices.

I'd like to run some "desktop" tests using the same kernel version as what's in the hardware. As far as I can tell I can't run uCLinux on a desktop, so next best thing, I'd like to get **anything** running 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

You could always install **anything** and downgrade the kernel. You can have multiple kernel entries in GRUB and choose the one you want on boot up. Just install the relevant kernel package from [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org) and you're good to go.

That said, I'm sure you can find snapshots of older releases<del>, Ubuntu provides them [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/), for example. Perhaps Ubuntu 4.10 was using the 2.4 kernel, I haven't been able to check it.</del>

As Karan pointed out in the comment below, Warty Warthog did not use the 2.4 kernel. I still think the easiest thing would be to just install an older kernel on a simple distro.

Comment: The first official Ubuntu release was 4.10 "Warty Warthog", and it used [kernel version 2.6.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions).

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good place for you to start to compile your own.

http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/202/1

I think Debian 3.1 uses 2.4

http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... quick answer, look at ftp://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/obsolete/309/iso/.  According to https://www.scientificlinux.org/about/history.short, the Scientific Linux 3.0 series is on 2.4 kernel.  I imagine you want i386 and not x64.

About ucLinux, it looks like you could run it on an old Palm Pilot emulator.  It seems to have been outdated years ago, but Wikipedia had some information on building it in Linux. Look up Xcopilot.